# My FPS fall drastically when recording a video

Tags: opencv

I'm using OpenCV to record video for a Full HD Camera Running at 30 FPS. I know the FPS of the camera because I measure it by counting the number of valid frames (this also coincides with the specifications). I do this by using a 5 ms second timer. Here is the code that I run each 5 ms.

```
cv::Mat frame;
if (capture.read(frame)){

    showCurrentFrame(frame);
    fpsCounter.newFrame();

    ui->labelVideo->setText("Video (" + QString::number(frame.cols) + "x" + QString::number(frame.rows) + ")");
    ui->labFPS->setText("FPS: " + QString::number(fpsCounter.getFPS()));

    if (isRecording){
        recorder << frame;
        fpsRecordCounter++;
    }

}
```

I set the FPS of the recorded video to 30 when I press the "Start Recording Button"

```
    recorder.open(currentVideoFile.toStdString(),
                  VIDEO_CODEC_FOURCC, // Tells it to record MJPEG
                  VIDEO_REC_FPS,  // Define with 30
                  frameSize)){  // 1920x1080
```

I've developed my Program in my workstation which runs Centos 7 using Qt and OpenCV 2.4.5. When I record in the desktop PC the FPS show consistently to be about 30.

However, this needs to record from a moving car. So I copy-pasted the code AS IS into my laptop and compiled it with zero issues.

My laptop uses Debian Testing and OpenCV 2.4.9. It is HERE that the slowdown is observed.

Since I'm using Qt I need to process the cv::Mat in order to display it. I do this in the showCurrentFrame function.

If I deactivate this function when recording I get maybe 23 FPS (and can't see what I'm recording)
If I leave it as is in the code above I get about 16~17 FPS.

The first thing that I thought was that my computer was not powerful enough, but it shouldn't be. This is the model:

https://www.asus.com/Notebooks/ASUS_VivoBook_S550CA/specifications/

It's the I5 variant with 500 Gb of HDD.

So I'm at a loss. Is it some sort of bug on OpenCV that was introduced in newer openCV versions or is it simply that my laptop is not powerful enough?

Comment: How much megabyte is each of the encoded frames? What's the writing speed of your notebook HDD? Can you try to just encode the frames using `cv::imencode(".jpg", image, buffer, params)` without using the VideoWriter to test, whether it is more likely that the frame drops occur from encoding or from writing to disk? If you have enough memory, you could try to buffer the images and write them to file in a different thread, but depending on the length of your video sequences that might or might not be any help.

Comment: Another thing: is your 16 FPS constant, or do you start with higher dps and have frame drops at some random point, loosing a lot of frames and continuing faster later on? I had some problems using devian in 2013, where I saved a lot of raw data. I solved this by writing in a different thread, so typically I was writing fast enough to keep the buffer empty, but once in a while the OS did something and interrupted my writing, in that time the buffer went up to like 100 buffered frames which could be written fast enough afterwards (after the OS finished its stuff) without losing anything.

Comment: HI. HDD speed is NOT the issue. The line recorder << frame uses about 28 ms which is WAY to high for recording at 30 FPS. I've tried to record the video in the solid state drive of my notebook and there was ZERO difference. So that much I'm sure. I've already tried the thread approach but as you can imagine, loosing about 7 Full HD frames per seconds, I quickly run out of memory. Videos would need to be super short.  I can try what you suggested, it is just that I don't know how (imencode) could you give me an example?

Comment: `vector<unsigned char>buff; 
Mat img = yourHDimage;
imencode(".jpg",img,buff);` Once done that you can display buff.size() in your qt output, too, to get an impression on the size of each encoded frames. But please remove the recording part of your code during that test. And once testes, please try the fps of your code just displaying the image, without any recording nor encoding.

Comment: Imho you shouldn't run your code each 5 ms. Instead, send a signal after your code has finished and connect that signal to the capturing slot. Not sure how the timer will behave if you call the function while it is still running. Maybe there are some interferences.

Comment: As I've said in the post, without recording I get 30 fps just fine. The problem is clearly the recording.  There is, sitll, somehting I don't understand. What is the purpose of your test? If I encode the images and buffer them, without ever clearing the buffer I will still run out of memory. Or are you suggesting that I encode them and the save them as I encode them?

Comment: no, just encode and font buffer. Just capture, display encode (and dont save or buffer or anything - just clear the buffer afterwards). You'll see whether encoding itself is slow enough to explain the frame drop. You obly wrote that it has 30 fps on the workstation (with recording).

Comment: Ahh ok. As soon as I can, I'll attempt what you are asking and see if anything changes.

Comment: Hi. I've replace the recording line with the line that you've provided. It did help a lot. FPS did not fall as encoding took approx 17 ms and the size of eack image was approximately 34 k.

Comment: If you just write the so-encoded data to a file (not with VideoRecorder but with some std file writing) do you get the same frame drops as in your initial code?

Comment: Correction, I meant to say 340k. The size is small enough to attempt to buffer all frames and THEN save them all to the VideoCapture. (Each video should only be about 1000 frames tops). So how can I turn the buffer into a cv::Mat in order to test this?

Comment: I've just read your comment as I was about to write. I'll try it ASAP

Comment: Hmmm I'm having trouble doing this. I've added the line "cv::imwrite(name.toStdString(), buff)" where name is #.jpg (where # is an increasing counter). However all recorded images are 0 bytes in size. How should I be writing each individual image?

Comment: I didn't mean to write images at all, just the raw data, using something like fprint or std::ofstream (you won't be able to view them as a video then). It's just to test whether separate encoding and writing of the data will give the same problem as using VideoWriter class (which encodes and writes internally). Then it would probably be a writing problem (like disk management or writing speed). If you instead want to buffer the whole camera stream you can offline (non timecritical) decode them back to `cv::Mat` one by one with `cv::imdecode` and then push them to your VideoWriter class.

Comment: Ok. I've added these lines:  std::ofstream outfile(name.toStdString(), std::ios_base::binary);  std::copy(buff.begin(),buff.end(), std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(outfile)); outfile.close(); . Again FPS did not fall. I'm going to try to buffer. Question. If I encode and then decode, don't I loose a lot of information??

Comment: Ok. Correction. I did the math better now. It did fall. Just buffering I got 29 FPS and by Saving it dropped to 27 fps. But it is still WAY better than the 16 FPS I've got from before.....

Comment: yes, you are right, encoding and decoding and again encoding could mean a loss of information. Are you using debug or release libraries?

Comment: Release libraries. Why?

Comment: debug libraries could be a huge performance issue :)

Comment: Yeah makes sense. Welll thanks for your help.